# Maven dependency error (artifact)

Tags: eclipse, maven

I'm trying to install Fenix framework with maven adding the following dependence:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>pt.ist</groupId>
    <artifactId>fenix-framework-backend-infinispan</artifactId>
    <version>2.0-cloudtm</version>
</dependency>
```

gives the following error: missing artifact ...

My POM.xml :

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.isban.test</groupId>
  <artifactId>fenixtest</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>fenixtest</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency> 
       <dependency>
        <groupId>pt.ist</groupId>
        <artifactId>fenix-framework-backend-infinispan</artifactId>
        <version>2.0-cloudtm</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>

<pluginRepositories>
  <pluginRepository>
    <id>fenix-ashes-maven-repository</id>
    <url>https://fenix-ashes.ist.utl.pt/maven-public</url>
  </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>

<repositories>
  <repository>
    <id>fenix-ashes-maven-repository</id>
    <url>https://fenix-ashes.ist.utl.pt/maven-public</url>
  </repository>
</repositories>

</project>
```

Official documentation : https://fenix-framework.github.io/Usage.html

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those artifacts are not available on Maven Central but on a specific Fénix repository. From the [official page](https://fenix-framework.github.io/Usage.html):

> These artifacts are available via the Fénix Framework Nexus repository, so you need to add it to your configuration:
>
> ```
> <pluginRepositories>
>   <pluginRepository>
>     <id>fenix-ashes-maven-repository</id>
>     <url>https://fenix-ashes.ist.utl.pt/maven-public</url>
>   </pluginRepository>
> </pluginRepositories>
>
> <repositories>
>   <repository>
>     <id>fenix-ashes-maven-repository</id>
>     <url>https://fenix-ashes.ist.utl.pt/maven-public</url>
>   </repository>
> </repositories>
> ```

There is actually a typo in that page, that I corrected here: the last element should be `<repositories>` and not `<pluginRepositories>`. Therefore, you need to add those repositories to your POM (or to your Maven settings).

The dependency

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>pt.ist</groupId>
  <artifactId>fenix-framework-backend-infinispan</artifactId>
  <version>2.0-cloudtm</version>
</dependency>
```

is also incorrect from the documentation: that artifact indeed [doesn't exist](https://fenix-ashes.ist.utl.pt/nexus/content/repositories/fenix-ashes-maven-repository/pt/ist/fenix-framework-backend-infinispan/). The latest version is 2.6.2 and the artifact should be `fenix-framework-backend-infinispan-code-generator`, so you should have instead:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>pt.ist</groupId>
  <artifactId>fenix-framework-backend-infinispan-code-generator</artifactId>
  <version>2.6.2</version>
</dependency>
```